# Subclassing AFHTTPRequestOperation

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, hierarchy, afnetworking-2

I'm working on network layer that uses `AFNetworking 2.0` library as its base. I'm planning to create the separate classes for each of request and to use `AFHTTPRequestOperation` as a base class.
So I have something like:

```
ABCLoginOperation : AFHTTPRequestOperation
```

Each custom wrapper class has some additional properties for convenient work with request/response parameters.
So in my case a workflow is the following:

1. Create `ABCLoginOperation` class instance;
2. Configure `ABCLoginOperation` by setting its additional properties;
3. Run `ABCLoginOperation` by adding it to any `NSOperationQueue`.

The implementation of what I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

```
ABCLoginOperation *loginOperation = [[ABCLoginOperation alloc] init];
ABCLoginRequestModel *requestModel = operation.requestModel;
requestModel.username = @"username";
requestModel.password = @"password";
[ABCOperationManager enqueueOperation:operation];
```

The issue is that `AFHTTPRequestOperation` doesn't know anything about my additional properties that I use to describe the request parameters and I have to fix this problem between step 2 and step 3. 
So I've implemented a custom request manager `ABCOperationManager` that should set `AFHTTPRequest's` properties based on `ABCLoginOperation's` properties. I thought it would be possible to create `NSURLRequestObject`, to set its parameters based on the properties of `ABCLoginOperation` object and to set this `NSURLRequestObject` to `request` property that `AFHTTPRequestOperation`/`AFURLConnectionOperation` uses in its implementation. So the implementation of `ABCOperationManager's` `enqueueOperation:` method is something like this:

```
- (void)enqueueOperation:(ABCOperation *)operation {
    [self configureOperation:operation];
    [self.operationQueue addOperation:operation]; //or use AFHTTPOperationManager's operation queue
}

- (void)configureOperation:(ABCOperation *)operation {
    NSMutableURLRequest *mutableURLRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[operation getRequestPath]] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:operation.timeoutInterval];
    //some further configuration of mutableUrlRequest    
    operation.request = mutableURLRequest //the problem
}
```

But the problem is that `request` property of `AFHTTPRequestOperation` is readonly and it can be set only in constructor. So it seems like there is no way to pre-configure my `ABCOperation` because the only way to create it is to use -`initWithRequest:` constructor. This makes `AFHTTPRequestOperation` subclassing rather useless from my standpoint. Could you please try to explain me what I am doing wrong and what's the correct way of creating some custom wrapper layer around `AFNetworking 2.0`? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.5.4/

Comment: Request operations are initialized with a request, and are immutable after that. You could override the `request` property to be `readwrite` in your subclass, but I wouldn't recommend it.